# Which one is good Microservice design?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am creating microservices that represents product catalog.

Microservice 1 : Returns product info like ID, Name, Desc, Price(USD)

Microservice 2 : Currency exchange service. If I give 10, and ask for USD to INR, it will return 700

Microservice 3 : It consolidates both by making a WebClient API call. I send request to Microservice 1 and retrieve product info, and for each price mentioned, I will make a call to Microservice 2 to get the exchange value.

So here Microservice 3 Calls Microservice 2, Microservice 3

But I am confused. It can also work this way..

Microservice 1 calls Microservice 2, Microservice 2 calls Microservice 3.

Which one is ideal?

Comment: this is more a question for stack exchange than stack overflow

Comment: 1st is not a microservice logically. It looks but only technically. 
It is just a data provider. What is the role of the 3rd ? Who is a client of your services?

Comment: Third service is kind of like an aggregator. It is to consolidate the results of both. Well, I just need a simple scenario of three or more Mmicroservices talking to each other. This is what I figured out. Any better use case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that the first method is ideal, where you have microservice 3 that sits in front of you two other services and consolidates the API, look up api-gateway this design pattern is fairly common :), if I have correctly understood the architecture

Answer (score 0):

Highly maintainable and testable - enables rapid and frequent development and deployment

Loosely coupled with other services - enables a team to work independently the majority of time on their service(s) without being impacted by changes to other services and without affecting other services

Independently deployable - enables a team to deploy their service without having to coordinate with other teams

Capable of being developed by a small team - essential for high productivity by avoiding the high communication head of large teams